# Adding numeric values in one CSV to those in another CSV based on matching another value in the same row

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison, addition

I've been tasked with using Powershell to count the number of occurrences where a particular action occurs in an application on a remote system.  The count of actions is already being put into a CSV file every 30 minutes, each file overwriting the previous one, though I can make a copy of the file to act as the "old" version.  The number of rows never exceeds 100-200 rows.  I believe the logic would be:

1. Every 30 minutes, import both the old and new CSV files.
2. Cycle through each row in the new CSV file and determine if there is a matching value in the "Action" column of the old CSV file.
3. If a matching value is found, add the "Count" field from the new CSV file to the "Count" field in the old CSV file in the row matching the "Action" field.
4. If no matching value is found, append the "Count" and "Action" fields to the end of the old CSV file.

For example, the "new file" should be added to the "old file in its original form" to equal the "old file after update".

*I've tried multiple times to post an example, but even though the formatting is showing that I've got it correct when I review the post, when it's actually posted, it gets all messed up - hopefully the logic I laid out before is enough.  Here's just a Notepad paste (which I know looks terrible; I'm not quite sure how to get it formatted properly):

New file
Count   Action
6   Apples
5561    Oranges
5   Bananas
324 Kiwis
8   Grapefruits

Old file in its original form:
Count Action
14  Apples
1   Pomegranate
5205    Oranges
491 Kiwis
1   Grapefruits

Old file after update:
Count Action
20  Apples
1   Pomegranate
10766   Oranges
5   Bananas
815 Kiwis
9   Grapefruits
*

The code I have is still very bare-bones; I can see what needs to happen, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around exactly how to get Powershell to perform the work.  Looks like I picked a bad week to switch to decaf.

```
# Define the script's name and location, move to that location
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$CurrentLocalFolder = "$scriptPath"
Set-Location -Path $CurrentLocalFolder

# Define file names and locations
$OriginalCSVFilename = "ActionReport_Count.csv"
$OriginalCSVFilepath = $CurrentLocalFolder + "\Output\" + $OriginalCSVFilename
$OriginalCSVFilepath = $OriginalCSVFilepath.ToString()
$NewCSVFilename = "ActionReport_Count_New.csv"
$NewCSVFilepath = $CurrentLocalFolder + "\Output\" + $NewCSVFilename
$NewCSVFilepath = $NewCSVFilepath.ToString()

# Import files
$OriginalCSVFile = Import-CSV -Path $OriginalCSVFilepath -Delimiter ","
$NewCSVFile = Import-CSV -Path $NewCSVFilepath -Delimiter ","

# Perform comparisons to know which fields to add to
ForEach ($NewRow in $NewCSVFile) {
    ForEach ($OldRow in $OriginalCSVFile) {
        If ($NewRow.Name -eq $OldRow.Name) {
            # Some kind of magic happens here
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your sample data - please replace it with the actual **raw text data**, not an attempt at a markdown table :)

Comment: Strangely, it looks perfect when I review the post, but gets messed up after I actually post it.  I just took it out to save confusion.

Comment: As I mentioned, please just post the raw text (eg. just open the file with notepad and copy-paste, or do `Get-Content sample.csv -Raw |Set-Clipboard`), don't attempt any formatting - I'll happily help you format it afterwards :)

Comment: ... or you could use the three backticks as a fence around the data.

Comment: Have you looked into Join-Object...  This is a module that has been posted a few times in this area.

Comment: Ok, I've pasted the sample data from notepad, and it put each bit on one line which makes me cringe.  "Count" and "Action" are the two headers with the numbers under "Count" and the fruit under "Action" (I had to change the actions to something else for the Internet; I have no why I used fruit; I might have been hungry.

Comment: I will try out Join-Object, thanks!!!